# Difference between Java and C# in Declaring and Initializing variables

Tags: java, c#, static, initialization, declaration

Usually in `java` you can declare an instance variable then initialize it inside the constructor or inside a method.

But When i tried to do that in `C#` it gave me an error saying it needs to be a static variable.

In this image I declared an instance variable of MailMerger object then I initialized it inside the constructor. But when I tried to use the instance, it gave me an error asking for it to be `static`.

[image]

Can anyone please explain to me the reason behind that please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW, this would yield the same error in Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a non static member from a static method which is not allowed as the error says.. You can fix it by Making `MailMerger` static as well

```
Class Program
{
    static MailMerger merge;

    //rest of your code
}
```

Another option is creating an instance of `MailMerger` within the static method.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was just confused, because in java i only used the instance in none static method, but I never realized that, So there is no actual difference between java and C#,both will give an error, i just wasn't informed enough, Thank you for clarifying again.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the `Main` method is static while `merge` variable is in instance-scope.

You should change the constructor to static and also the variable.

Comment: I know how to fix it, i was just wondering about on how it works on java, but you made me realize that it only works in none static methods even in java, so there is no actual difference I was just confused. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You declered a `MailMerger` in `Program` constructor, but you have to create an instance of `Program` in `Main` method. In your `Main` method you are calling `merge` which was never initialized. If you create a new instance of `Program` class, like this:

```
Program p = new();
```

Than you can call the the `merge` field:

```
p.merge.Merge();
```